# About android studio setup

Tags: android-studio

When I download and install the android studio and start it for the first time,I doesn't get the android wizard setup window and android studio directly started. For your better understanding I uploaded an image of window which I am expecting.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMLTj.jpg)

How can I get this window..?